# What is the correct way of positioning UI components

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering, when creating a UI (such as main menu) and you need to position buttons around the screen, do you position things using margins(by using exact dp values) or do you align things in reference to the screen boundaries (left and right to screen..etc)

I am not asking about opinion here. I am asking about the right or the most common way.

I can see it is super easy to drag and drop components in the editor however I am always worried about different screens so I end up trying to relate everything (which takes much more time to do).

I wonder if I am doing things the wrong way

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support different screen types(for example landscape screen, different dpi versions) you can read this guide : [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: well, i haven't designed layout for a long time but what i do is align components to components if needed, use padding, and use gravity especially on layouts, and what i do is use 2 same layouts one in layout folder and the other one is layout-sw600dp(for landscape put the layout in the layout-land folder, if you don't have those folders just create it). that's all i know

Comment: @manola yes exactly you know . I will suggest create a simple project and try to create new layouts and test them. I always practise when learning new things , just try and getting better , understand correctly

Comment: designing layouts isn't really that easy, sometimes it takes me hours to just  put a component below another one

Comment: @rmanalo yes you are right , when i started it took me too. But now i can create layouts more easily and align components . I am saying again if you do nothing you cant think about it, just try and practice and getting better.

Comment: I read this link and this is realyl yhe first thing anyone would read when learning android. But it does not answer my question. This link explains concepts but does not talk about layout alignment. Thats why I asked you questions

Comment: @Snake and i am saying to you we can use relative layout or linear layout , align components to screen boundaries or give components any margin attribute to align , padding too. I am saying again it depends for your purpose. Create any layout and decide which layout you will create. And then try to create it. When you created it try to support multiple layout types. And then you do it correctly and successfully. I didnt see any xml file in your question try to create some layouts.